# Orthonormal basis for a vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or Disprove: If V is any vector space and with an orthonormal basis *B* for a subspace W of V, then V has an orthonormal basis *C* with *B* as a subset of *C*.

First Question: Can you have an orthonormal basis for any vector space or can you only have an orthonormal basis for inner product spaces?

Second Question: Does it also make a difference whether or not V is finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional?

Comment: "ortho" requires IPS, "normal" required normed vector space. All IPS's are NVS's so you need an IPS.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

How would you define "orthonormal" if you do not have an inner product defined

Second question:

Infinite dimensional spaces are a different story in that you have different types of bases, depending on whether you "allow" infinite sums or not.